# C# Inheritance, adding new methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

Ok so I've been searching about for a while trying to find an anwer to this question but it is difficult to phrase so I am asking here.

I'm inheriting a class like

```
Class A (int a, int b, int c)

public A(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

Class B : A 

public B(int a, int b, int c) base: (a, b, c)

public void blah(int something)
{

}
```

Why can't I do this and then do :

```
B classb = new B(1,2,3);

classb.blah(4);
```

Instead I have to do

```
public virtual void blah(int something)
{
}
```

In class A, then in class B:

```
public override void blah(int something)
{
 //method to be used in B but not A.
}
```

So even though I have no intention of ever using the method in class A I still have to declare the virtual? So if i'm inheriting class C : B then what? I have to declare stuff in A for C?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Are you sure you're posting the correct code?

Comment: The code you have pasted is not even close to valid C#.  It's not clear at all what it is trying to convey.  Please fix your example code.

Comment: Fixed it when I saw tigrans response. In my code i'm not actually using these specific class names or method names, I just typed something out that approximates what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption has no any meaning, at least as much as I understood.

Consider following example:

```
public class Base {}

public class Derived : Base {
    public void DerivedSpecificMethod() {
    }
}
```

if you do

```
Derived d = new Derived(); //as you specify in code example 
d.DerivedSpecificMethod(); //you CAN do this.
```

The `virtual` may be need in case when you write:

```
Base b = new Derived(); //note, I use a Base here on left side of equation
b.DerivedSpecificVirtualMethod(); //virtual method call
```

Comment: My issue was that I was doing A classb = new B(1,2,3)

Comment: @Tim: yes in that case you may need virtual keyword, to make it work.

Comment: @Tim you could also do a cast `A classb = new B(1,2,3); ((b)classb).blah();`. However this suggests either you'll need to inspect the type before the cast or you're unnecessarily declaring the variable as the base type.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I do this and then do :
>
> ```
> B classb = new B(1,2,3);
>
> classb.blah(4);
> ```

You absolutely can. There's no problem with that at all, other than the syntactic errors in your code. Here's a complete example which compiles and runs with no issues. (I've fixed the naming convention violation at the same time for the `blah` method.)

```
using System;

class A
{
    public A(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {
    }

    public void Blah(int something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.Blah");
    }
}



class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B(1, 2, 3);
        b.Blah(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this, except that your code is not actually valid C#. I think this is what you want:

```
class A
{
    public A(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public B(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, c)
    {
    }

    public void blah(int something)
    {
    }
}
```

Then this is no problem:

```
B classb = new B(1,2,3);
classb.blah(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile. You don't have to use `virtual` specifier, this works as expected:

```
class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B classb = new B(1,2,3);
        classb.blah(4);
    }
}

class A
{
    public A(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public B(int a, int b, int c): base (a, b, c)
    {
    }

    public void blah(int something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(something);
    }
}
```